# R throws an error when importing a valid .zip file

Tags: r, unzip, fread

I manually downloaded a zip file throught [this link](https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/despesas-execucao/202001) and I was able to save, unzip it and open its content (a .csv file), no problem at all.

However, when I tried to import into R I got problems:

```
test_file <- paste0(dest_path,"/test.zip") ### ok
download.file("https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/despesas-execucao/202001"
, destfile = test_file ) ### ok
    
unzip(test_file, exdir = paste0(dest_path,"/unzipped")) #### ERROR!!!
```

The reported error is:

```
Error in unzip(test_file, exdir = paste0(dest_path, "/unzipped")) : 
  zip error: `Cannot open zip file `x:\test.zip` for reading` in file `zip.c:140`
```

I also tried the `data.table::fread()`, it seems that the same error occurs.

OBS: When comparing the character stream of the two files, I noticed that they are quite the same, but the one imported through  download.file has extra empty lines.

What might be going on?

```
dt <- fread("https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/despesas-execucao/202001"
             , verbose = T)
```

Output:

```
OpenMP version (_OPENMP)       201511
  omp_get_num_procs()            4
  R_DATATABLE_NUM_PROCS_PERCENT  unset (default 50)
  R_DATATABLE_NUM_THREADS        unset
  R_DATATABLE_THROTTLE           unset (default 1024)
  omp_get_thread_limit()         2147483647
  omp_get_max_threads()          4
  OMP_THREAD_LIMIT               unset
  OMP_NUM_THREADS                unset
  RestoreAfterFork               true
  data.table is using 2 threads with throttle==1024. See ?setDTthreads.
 Downloaded 5333397 bytes...Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
[01] Check arguments
  Using 2 threads (omp_get_max_threads()=4, nth=2)
  NAstrings = [<<NA>>]
  None of the NAstrings look like numbers.
  show progress = 1
  0/1 column will be read as integer
[02] Opening the file
  Opening file C:\Users\fabio\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMZnoDr\file5b463781124.
  File opened, size = 5.062MB (5307463 bytes).
  Memory mapped ok
[03] Detect and skip BOM
  Last byte(s) of input found to be 0x00 (NUL) and removed.
[04] Arrange mmap to be \0 terminated
  \n has been found in the input and different lines can end with different line endings (e.g. mixed \n and \r\n in one file). This is common and ideal.
  File ends abruptly with 'P'. Final end-of-line is missing. Using cow page to write 0 to the last byte.
[05] Skipping initial rows if needed
  Positioned on line 1 starting: <<PK>>
[06] Detect separator, quoting rule, and ncolumns
  Detecting sep automatically ...
  sep=','  with 2 lines of 2 fields using quote rule 0
  sep='|'  with 2 lines of 3 fields using quote rule 0
  Detected 3 columns on line 7. This line is either column names or first data row. Line starts as: <<µTŸ   I>>
  Quote rule picked = 0
  fill=false and the most number of columns found is 3
[07] Detect column types, good nrow estimate and whether first row is column names
  Number of sampling jump points = 100 because (5305832 bytes from row 1 to eof) / (2 * 722 jump0size) == 3674
  A line with too-few fields (2/3) was found on line 2 of sample jump 0. 
  Type codes (jump 000)    : CCC  Quote rule 0
Types in 1st data row match types in 2nd data row but previous row has 2 fields. Taking previous row as column names.  All rows were sampled since file is small so we know nrow=1 exactly
[08] Assign column names
[09] Apply user overrides on column types
Error in fread("https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/despesas-execucao/202001",  : 
  embedded nul in string: '\024+¹a¶\032ÛWro8v\003z§\037<ÄRþð<\tMËåtÄãVëª\bÓ*¡†ÿ]Ü\005£â} ¨¤WÚSøñþcLLÛbÄºŽçP\026üügLô\021ÄŒg3ºÜO\fÎ?]Î-}\033þ¿µÂ ~Ž´X"x4Çï±\\¼¹\rø\025æy?‹\026wQ¦&\030'7¿aX©\004,ß‡Õ"ðá\024¸ï\215\200Cêm\006nŸ'¹(ôà\215vï]èóžÝ±\0[”íÎc\177à\001ª”ë¸&c[>øÂÎÓâU+ÁåL\016]'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In fread("https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/despesas-execucao/202001",  :
  Previous fread() session was not cleaned up properly. Cleaned up ok at the beginning of this fread() call.
2: In fread("https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/despesas-execucao/202001",  :
  Detected 2 column names but the data has 3 columns (i.e. invalid file). Added 1 extra default column name for the first column which is guessed to be row names or an index. Use setnames() afterwards if this guess is not correct, or fix the file write command that created the file to create a valid file.
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you extract the zip file to your local disk and import CSV manually? I think the problem is in the csv file.

Comment: `unzip()` worked for me, and then I was able to read the .csv without error using `read.csv("202001_Despesas.csv", fileEncoding="latin1")`.  I'd guess something local to you (e.g. a virus checker?) is interfering with the download.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, the problem is that when we download the file using download.file, then I cant unzip. When I download manually, I can unzip and read tyhe csv.  I have edited the question to make this point clear. Thank you.

Comment: `download.file(..., mode="wb")`?

Comment: @r2evans, it worked  with the magic mode="wb".  Would you please answer by posting so I make it the chosen solution? Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up front:

```r
download.file("https://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/download-de-dados/despesas-execucao/202001"
, mode = "wb"
, destfile = test_file )
```

[`download.file`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) (on windows) tries to differentiate the text/binary determination based on the filename; if it is not "known", then it defaults to a text download, which corrupts binary files. Note this is mostly for windows:

> The choice of binary transfer ('mode = "wb"' or '"ab"') is
> important on Windows, since unlike Unix-alikes it does distinguish
> between text and binary files and for text transfers changes '\n'
> line endings to '\r\n' (aka 'CRLF').
>
> On Windows, if 'mode' is not supplied ('missing()') and 'url' ends
> in one of '.gz', '.bz2', '.xz', '.tgz', '.zip', '.jar', '.rda',
> '.rds' or '.RData', 'mode = "wb"' is set so that a binary transfer
> is done to help unwary users.

In your case, the URL has no such extension, so it defaults to `mode = "w"`.

Comment: I opened an issue in data.table relating this problem, I mentioned you insight: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5237 . Regards

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me: `fread` does not support `.zip` files, regardless of whether it uses `curl::curl_download` or `download.file` (for which it *does* default to `mode="wb"`). Seeing as how they have an open issue for this ([#3834](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3834)), your issue seems a duplicate of that (ignoring that there is no clear file extension to determine compression, one of `.gz` or `.bz2`).